# MVC Routing catch-all and WebApi

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have an MVC app that also needs to serve up webapi requests. There is already in place some MVC routing, the last route being a catch all route to redirect to an error page. The `WebApiConfig` is the default as set up by Visual Studio. This final MVC catch all route is catching the `/api` calls and consequently the webapi calls never reach the endpoint.

I understand that routes are processed using the *first match approach*, but I thought that the `/api` calls would be ignored by any MVC routing and just passed to the webapi router.

Is there any way of having a catch-all MVC route that does not catch `/api` calls?

Answer (score 0):

The order you configure routes is important because of the first match approach. If you configure the web api routes before the MVC routes then that should avoid the web api routes being caught by MVC route provided there was a match found by web api.

Make sure the web api route table configuration is done before the MVC route table configuration.

```cs
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```